# Is Anchor a language or a framework?

Tags: anchor, rust

I am confused about what exactly Anchor is. I saw a tweet from a Solana Dev Rel, he responded to a question related to Move programming language.

"I do not think Move will replace anchor lang. I believe Move is just another language to onboard devs to Solana.

Time will tell which language gets the majority. My bet is on anchor lang"

This answer got me confused. As much as I understand, Move is a programming language but Anchor is a Rust-based framework. How are these two comparable? Also, I realized Anchor's official website is called anchor-lang.com but on website homepage it says "Solana's Sealevel runtime framework"

I'm lost in this language and framework dilemma.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Anchor Lang is a framework built on top of the Solana Native development framework. Both use Rust as a language.

The Anchor framework makes a lot of things easier by making opinionated choices on deserialization, account management, and more. It's much like using Spring-boot or some other framework instead of the base language to quickly write Solana Programs.

Answer (score 0):

anchor is solana development framework, built by armani ferrante.

Answer (score -2):

Its a framework for Solana contracts development.